# 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in mscorlib.dll. ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Скачал пример интернет-магагзина SportStore, который создан по книге ASP.NET MVC 5 Freeman. Но проект не запускается, выдает вот эту ошибку:

An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error
>   occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner
>   exception for details. --->  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   Invalid column name 'ImageMimeType'. at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlExcep‌​tion
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection –

```
public ViewResult List(string category, int page = 1) {

        ProductsListViewModel viewModel = new ProductsListViewModel {
            Products = repository.Products
                .Where(p => category == null || p.Category == category)
                .OrderBy(p => p.ProductID)
                .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
                .Take(PageSize),
            PagingInfo = new PagingInfo {
                CurrentPage = page,
                ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                TotalItems = category == null ?
                    repository.Products.Count() :
                    repository.Products.Where(e => e.Category == category).Count()
            },
            CurrentCategory = category
        };
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Comment: inner exception?

Comment: System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'ImageMimeType'. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection

Comment: что у Вас есть сказать по поводу поля `ImageMimeType`?

Comment: Добавил в таблицу ImageMimeType, но не помогло

Comment: прямо совсем ничего не изменилось?

Comment: Нет, та же ошибка